# If $\sum_n a_n $ converges and $a_n > 0$, is it true that $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n}$ is also convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Assume that $\sum_n a_n $ is convergent and $a_n > 0$, is it true that $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n}$ is also convergent? What can you comment on $∑_n a_n^2$?

I have thought that since summation an is convergent that $\lim_{n \to ∞} a_n = 0$ so $\lim_{n \to ∞} \sqrt{a_n}$ must also be $0$, hence it is convergent.

We can't really say about $a_n^2$.

Is this right? Can anyone suggest a different approach to this? Thanks.

Comment: what can we say about summation of absolute an?

Comment: I'm not sure I can decode the first part. If $∑_n a_n = 0$ and $a_n > 0$, then all $a_n = 0$.

Comment: Also note that $∑_n a_n$ converges implies $a_n \to 0$, but the converse doesn't hold.

Comment: Taking $a_n=1/n^2$, the sum of $a_n$ converges (not to zero !) but not the sum of $\sqrt a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hint: consider
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}
$$

Second hint: if $0<a<1$, then $a^2<a$. If $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent, then $0<a_n<1$ for $n>n_0$, for some $n_0$; thus the inequality $a_n^2<a^n$ holds for $n>n_0$. What can you say about a series with positive terms that's bounded above by a convergent series (from some point on)?

---

Comment: the condition that a sequence $(a_n)$ converges to zero doesn't imply the series $\sum_n a_n$ converges (which is your error in the first case).

Comment: if i assume an= n^(-2) that will say root an to be divergent. and an^2 to be convergent does that always hold true or for this particular assumption?

Comment: @rohit The series $\sum_{n>0}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent; what about $\sum_{n>0}\frac{1}{n}$? If you find a counterexample to a statement, then the statement is false.

Comment: yeah summation 1/n^2 is convergent and summation 1/n is divergent and summation 1/n^4 is convergent so do i can always say that summation  of root an is divergent and summation of n^2 is convergent?

Comment: @rohit For the second question, it's not sufficient to find an example.